# Cannot add files to Visual studio 2015 (Community) Update 3 / TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tfs, checkin

I added some C# files that are part of a database project, then delete the EDMX (Entity Framework File) to start again after a mess up, visual studio TFS got excited and marked the files for delete) TFS is NOT my most favourite piece of software. SO OK I think - let it delete them and I will re-add said files and check in later.
Ha ha - On "Add Existing files" (select the files) / OK --- Visual studio simply silently does not add them - it does not complain, just nothing.

NB: I  did do a TFS scorch to clean the workspace after the check in having saved a copy of the directory for these kind of gotchas. So that I can emulate a clean get on my machine to correct any forgotten checkins

Maybe I should add them directly into the csproj file using notepad++

Comment: ooops! I see some of these files I was trying to add (to fix the build break) were generated by the edmx file and so when I add them directly they are added manically by VS under the edmx/tt file (or just ignored as   a reference existed there?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to install [TFS Powertools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power), this tool provides additional Visual Studio menu options and functions:

First, map the project to a clean workspace.

Then, copy the files you want to add to TFS to the workspace, under the correct folder.

Last, right click these file and select `Team Foundation Server` -- `Add`, you'll see these files show up in Source Control Explorer, and check them into TFS.

[image]

Comment: Ah! very useful thanks! Just what I need. Our guys seem to discourage the idea of separate work spaces, but I fail to see how you can guarantee your check in builds and passes tests other than relying on the build server. I have used TF Scorch for this, but even then it seems there are issues - with get latest.

Comment: I cant seem to accept your answer, there is no check box to accept, what do I need to do get the checkbox visible?